# maven repository location for hsqldb 2.0

Tags: maven-2, hsqldb

http://hsqldb.org/ - where is the maven repository for the latest version 2.0.0 bits

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to be deployed to REPO1 already; http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hsqldb/hsqldb/2.0.0/

Answer (score 33):

Just to clarify a bit, and to help anyone who gets here looking for a direct solution in the pom, the groupId has changed to reflect the new preferred syntax, so your pom.xml should contain:

```
<groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
<artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
<version>2.0.0</version>
```

Instead of:

```
<groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
<artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
<version>1.8.whatever</version>
```

The latter groupId doesn't contain anything newer than 1.8.0.10, which caught me out.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the latest version still hasn't been deployed to the central [Maven repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/hsqldb/hsqldb) or any other public repo available on the net. Until then you can [install](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html) it manually on your local machine or even better [deploy](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html) on your company's repository.

Comment: Do you know why this is still not in the MVN database?